# don't go to previous screen in android?

Tags: android

In my application i have two screen. Screen1 and screen2 . If i am in screen2 when i click the back button it shows the screen1. I need to close application at the time of clicking back button in the screen2 . How to do this???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you start screen2 from screen1 via an Intent.

After you call startActivity(screen2) you should close screen1, via the `finish()` call.

Something like:

```
Intent screen2=new Intent(Screen1.this,Screen2.class);
startActivity(screen2);
finish();
```

Comment: I use this code to call the screen2 .How to finish the first screen here.I am new to android so please ....
Intent i=new Intent(screen1.this,screen2.class);
startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

From http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
        && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
        && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
    // Take care of calling this method on earlier versions of
    // the platform where it doesn't exist.
    onBackPressed();
}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// This will be called either automatically for you on 2.0
// or later, or by the code above on earlier versions of the
// platform.
return;
}
```